# Возможно ли отключить майкросовтовский сервер, чтобы не мешал?

Tags: apache, веб-сервер, visual-studio

У меня установлена Visual Studio 2010 Express, со всем необходимым для работы веб, из-за которой у меня не работает сервер апач. Возможно ли отключить все, с чем работает Visual Studio 2010,чтобы не мешал серверу апач? Если да, то как сделать?

Answer (score 1):

IIS сервер [работает и с **php**](http://php.iis.net/) и с **asp.net**. Т.е. сайты на php можно запускать на IIS.

Comment: т.е хочу научиться делать сайты,чтобы работали на сервере апач, и созданные посредством asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 0):

Точно сейчас не скажу как, но можно, найти у себя панель управления ISS сервера и заверши там их, или через диспетчер сервисов в вин7, просто выключи его, или, можешь апач сменить на другой порт

Comment: когда меняю порт,то апач выдает следующее сообщение:[notice] Disabled use of acceptEx<> WinSock2 API. в диспетчере служб iis отключал работу сервера-безрезультатно. щас думаю другую ОС установить для обучения создания сайтов на php.

Comment: с остановленным сервером ,через диспетчер служб iis,работает сайт,если запустить его с визуал студии 2010экспрес. Хочется уметь разрабатывать сайты посредством php и c#

Comment: <small>Правильно, windows must die, ставь nix ^^</small>

Comment: "Bad coders must... study", а не то, что Вы, @AlexWindHope, написали...
Посмотрел бы я на Вас в 6 лет, работающих в Linux.